# How to add content after certain number of paragraph from a starting point in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I will live to add a div ( my contents ) after three paragraph of the first class "pane-node-title". Basically I have something like this

```
<div class="field-item even">
  <div>Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Cras ultricies ligula sed
    magna dictum porta. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Curabitur non nulla sit amet
    nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus.</div>
  <blockquote>
    <p>Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Cras ultricies ligula sed
      magna dictum porta. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Curabitur non nulla sit amet
      nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. HERE HERE</p>
  </blockquote>
  <p><img title="myTitle" height="100" width="100" src="someimage.png" alt=""></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Cras ultricies ligula sed
    magna dictum porta. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Curabitur non nulla sit amet
    nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. **I WANT TO INSERT A CONTENT AFTER THIS !!** </p>
  <blockquote>
    <p>Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Cras ultricies ligula sed
      magna dictum porta. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Curabitur non nulla sit amet
      nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus.</p>
  </blockquote>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Cras ultricies ligula sed
    magna dictum porta. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Curabitur non nulla sit amet
    nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

There may be multiple divs/spans/etc inside any div. However any image or video tag or embed tag needs to be ignored. So basically I want to travel the nth paragraph and insert some content.

***Basically as you can see , it is already three paragraph. And, hence add there. Aka, I want to add after three paragraph of page-node-title . A paragraph can be the p tag or div tag.***

So far I have something like

```
$(' >p:not(:empty):eq(3)').append('<p style="color: red">Hello Worldqw</p>');
```

Comment: Would you care to mark in your code where exactly you want the insertion. Do paragraphs in blockquotes count towards your total?

Comment: I just did that. You can see the text "**I WANT TO INSERT A CONTENT AFTER THIS !!**). It is at the end of that p. I am seriously confused with this!

Comment: @Okomikeruko Does that answer you question?

Comment: But none of your `<p>` elements have the class of `pane-node-title`; please, remove or reduce the unnecessary content of your code (the filler-text for example), add the relevant class-names you're working with to the relevant element(s), showing the input (the tidied up/clarified HTML above) and the desired output (where the new content should be, what the new content *is*), that way we can - hopefully - better help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k6b5sujo/)

```
$("<h1>InsertedAfter</h1>").insertAfter($('.title').nextAll('div').last())
```

Comment: Sorry mate. I was unclear with my description earlier.. Have a look at the description please. Thanks for it

Answer (score 0):

Or this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oLvjsghk/)

```
div:nth-of-type(4) {
   /* Code here */
}
```

Comment: Sorry mate. I was unclear with my description earlier.. Have a look at the description please. Thanks for it

Answer (score 0):

Check out this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kz7pr9d5/4/)**

```
$("div > p:nth-child(3n)").after( "<span>***Content***</span>" );
```

Comment: Sorry mate. I was unclear with my description earlier.. Have a look at the description please. Thanks for it